# Is there a difference between an array of Linked Lists and a Hash table?

Tags: arrays, linked-list, hashtable

My question is pretty much what's up above. According to the diagrams I see of a hashtable, it seems like for example:

Hashtable temp1 = new Hashtable(20);

SList[] temp2 = new SList[20];

Assuming SList is a singly linked list, isn't temp1 almost the same as temp2? I'm just trying to understand hash tables a little better. Thanks!

Comment: These two are distinct. A hashtable is indexed by some sort of an object called key of a type with a well-defined operation called `hash` defined on it. Depending on the value of the hash, the pair (Key, Value) is stored in the appropriate place in hash table. In general hash functions should have vastly different values for almost identical objects. Hashtables use lists to take care of collisions - distinct keys can yield the same hash - if so, they are stored at the same spot (in the corresponding list) in this model of collision resolution. Hashtables can use arrays of lists internally.

Comment: I see what you mean, but let's say you defined a separate class HashTableImplementation with the constructor being an array of Single linked lists. Because you're using single linked lists, collision is already taken care of and you can sort values of the same key in anyway you like. If you added a hash method to the HashTableImplementation as well as a compression function method to it, couldn't you have the exact same thing as a hash table?

Comment: Yes. But you could have also used another method of collision resolution and it'd be still a hash table. What's used inside - be it an array of linked lists or just a simple array, is just an implementation detail.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you both for the answers! It's only in the collision handing then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a hash table you insert a value V into a table with a key K. This K can be anything that can be processed by a hash function.

Insertion into `SList[]`, however, must be done using an integer index, which is far less flexible than being able to use any hashable object.

Beside this point there are several ways of dealing with collisions on a key in a hash table. Hashing with chaining produces something which resembles your aforementioned list of linked lists, with the added benefit of indexing by hashable objects instead of ints.

See [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) under Hashing for a description of others ways of dealing with hash collisions in a hash table.

Comment: But isn't the value returned by the hashcode() function an integer? So that it can be placed by index into the buckets, similar to the way an array of SLists does? But I understand what you're saying about the different collision handling scenarios, a Hash table does beat an array of SLists in that regard.

Comment: That's true, you could use an integer index passed through the hash function to determine the location in the table to put the value. The only difference in that situation would be that the hash table would perform more poorly than the array of linked lists, as performing the hashing function will take longer than a simple array index-based insertion.